# How To add css and js file 3columns.phtml page

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I am trying to add some additional css/js to the 3columns.phtml page. First I have tried to add it in page.xml page
`app/design/frontend/mytheme/layout/page.xml`

**My code is**

```
<page_three_columns translate="label">
        <label>All Three-Column Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
            <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>three_columns</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </page_three_columns>
```

But there was no change at the 3columns.phtml pages.Then I add the css/js files only at the catelog product view page, but no change. my default local.xml file

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/3columns.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

So Please tell me..Is that a correct way.. Is that any format to add js/css files at basic pages.. Please guide me

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Have you cleaned your cache? And have you applied your catalog to `3 columns`?

Comment: Yes i did...but no change..

Comment: What's the url? if you have it live.

Comment: Also are you editing `pag.xml` from your `path/to/your/theme/layout/`?

Comment: Sorry @Adarsh Khatri.. Now i am trying at localhost.....

Comment: page.xml path app/design/frontend/mytheme/layout/page.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24655/discussion-between-astro-and-adarsh-khatri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you are likely getting error on your package directory-

It should be-

```
app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layout/page.xml
```

and same thing in skin folder -

```
skin/frontend/my_package/my_theme/css
skin/frontend/my_package/my_theme/js
```